# Cannot connect Ethernet with an adapter through USB port

Tags: usb, ethernet, adapter

I am pretty new to Ubuntu. So, I bought an adapter to connect Ethernet through USB but it only shows connecting. It works on windows and mint but it's not working on Ubuntu. Please help.
I'm using ubuntu 22.04.
Here is what I got from running lsusb

```
 lsusb
 
 Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
 Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface 
 Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5a07 IMC Networks VGA UVC WebCam 
 Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8152 Fast Ethernet Adapter 
 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Try to install the updated driver: https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-usb-3-0-software

Answer (score 0):

The 10/100 Realtek RTL8152 USB network card is already supported by Ubuntu 22.04 by default. No extra driver is required.

Unfortunately some Realtek USB network cards have issues with USB power management and require power management to be disabled to work reliably. Just changing the USB port may also help.

In Ubuntu you can disable the USB power management for the device as follows:

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and add `usbcore.quirks=0bda:8152:k` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` entry. Example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="usbcore.quirks=0bda:8152:k"
```

Once you have edited the file, run the following command in terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And then reboot.